# Hitting enter in a form element triggering click function of some other element in same form

Tags: angular

I have a remove button and a text field for tags in my angular front end,

when i type tags and hit enter, the remove function is calling by default how can i solve this?

```
<button (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>

<div class="input">
 <app-ui-tags 
 </app-ui-tags>
 <label>Tags</label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default button type is `submit` in most browsers, so whenever you hit enter on the input the form is submitted and button 'clicked'. Change your button to:

```
<button type="button" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
```

Here is [demo with 2 forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vonmc2) - one with default button type the other with 'button' type.

Answer (score 1):

when you use Buttons like

```
 <button>Click to do something</button>
```

these are by default submit buttons,

use to prevent auto submit like this

```
<button type="button" (click)="remove(i)>Click to do something</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" (click)="remove(i)">
```

to change that. type="submit" is the default when you don't  give type 
   attribute